# Can this list be modified?

Tags: vb.net, readonly

Can this list and/or its content be modified despite it being `ReadOnly` ?

```
Public Shared ReadOnly CONST_PARAMS As New List(Of List(Of Double)) From {
                                    New List(Of Double) From {200.0, 913, 42, 3.1415},
                                    New List(Of Double) From {150.0, 923, 42, 3.1415},
                                    New List(Of Double) From {100.0, 933, 42, 3.1415}}
```

If the answer is yes, is [ReadOnlyCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) the best alternative?

Comment: Yes and yes. IReadOnlyList<T> might also be an alternative.

Comment: Remember: the reference and the object are two different things. The modifier applies to the reference, and calling an `Add()` method is still a `get` (read) operation from the point of the view of the reference.

Comment: You can't do this,  CONST_PARAMS = New List(Of List(Of Double)), in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this syntax can ever be useful to somebody, here goes:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly CONST_PARAMS As New ReadOnlyCollection(Of ReadOnlyCollection(Of Double)) _
            (New List(Of ReadOnlyCollection(Of Double)) From {
                                    New ReadOnlyCollection(Of Double)(New List(Of Double) From {200.0, 913, 42, 3.1415}),
                                    New ReadOnlyCollection(Of Double)(New List(Of Double) From {150.0, 923, 42, 3.1415}),
                                    New ReadOnlyCollection(Of Double)(New List(Of Double) From {100.0, 933, 42, 3.1415}),
                                    New ReadOnlyCollection(Of Double)(New List(Of Double) From {100.0, 943, 42, 3.1415})})
```